# Adding dates into existing feature class from Excel spreadsheet using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, excel, feature-class, date

I've been trying to load data from an excel spreadsheet into existing feature classes, but I've been having some trouble with the dates.

I've written a script that compares the values in the spreadsheet & in the feature class.

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(engPath, 'engPath')  
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('engPath', "NEW_SELECTION", d)
EngCursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor('engPath', '*')
for row in EngCursor:
    for item in Master_Dict.itervalues():
        print item[1], row[3]
        if item[1] == row[3]:
            i = 0
            j = 2
            while i < 34:
                if item[i] == row[j]:
                    print "Values are the same"
                else:
                    print "NOPE!", item[i], row[j]
                i+=1
                j+=1
```

When I run the script, I get values like this:

```
Excel Spreadsheet Value = "41526.0"
Feature Class Value = "2013-09-09 00:00:00"
```

Those two values are supposed to be identical, and the excel value for the cell does show
"09/09/2013".  I've checked the spreadsheet, and the column is set to a date data type.

I don't know how to tell arc that it is indeed looking at a date data type.

Comment: One approach is to convert your date-time value into a float value then do the comparison.

Comment: Why was this marked as off-topic?
This question is dealing with software development yes, but it's talking about loading data into Arc, a GIS platform.

In any case, I was able to figure out a solution using [xlrds' xldate_as_tuple method](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html#xlrd.xldate_as_tuple-function) and [using python's datetime module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#module-datetime)

Answer (score 1):

Using Python, this shows how to convert the Excel serial date to YYYY-MM-DD format.
 The Time portion is not included. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036709/when-reading-date-from-excel-using-xlrd-in-python-datetime-randomly-becomes-flo